# Convert ipywidget "interract" to timedelta: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: function

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying in a python 3 Jupyter notebook to use an interactive slider bar to output a value in seconds (timedelta) that I will use later to offset some data.

I defined the code like this:

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import datetime

def f(x):
    return x

time_switch = interact(f, x=(-200, 200, 10))
delay = datetime.timedelta(seconds = time_switch)
```

But this returns the error

```
----> delay = datetime.timedelta(seconds = time_switch)
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: function
```

How do I define the output of 'interact' to be a value and not a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer :)

"interact(function, x)" is not there to return a value that will vary with the slider. It is there to modify the content of the function with a value x provided by the slider.
To resolve the issue above, the code should be like this:

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import datetime

def f(x):
    delay = datetime.timedelta(seconds = x)
    # and the rest of the operations I want to do with "delay", plot etc... 
    return x

interact(f, x=(-200, 200, 10))
```